# Validaciones en jsf

Tags: html5, jsf

Buenas estoy en mi proyecto pero requiero hacer unas validaciones y que al momento de que el usuario ingrese sus datos en el login me muestre mensajes de bienvenida o error sea el caso pero estoy un poco perdido agradezco su colaboración.

**entidad mapeada**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Gil
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByIdusuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.idusuario = :idusuario"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.login = :login"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByNombre", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.nombre = :nombre")})
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "IDUSUARIO")
private Integer idusuario;
@Column(name = "LOGIN")
private String login;
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@Column(name = "NOMBRE")
private String nombre;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(Integer idusuario) {
    this.idusuario = idusuario;
}

public Integer getIdusuario() {
    return idusuario;
}

public void setIdusuario(Integer idusuario) {
    this.idusuario = idusuario;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idusuario != null ? idusuario.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Usuario)) {
        return false;
    }
    Usuario other = (Usuario) object;
    if ((this.idusuario == null && other.idusuario != null) || (this.idusuario != null && !this.idusuario.equals(other.idusuario))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Usuario[ idusuario=" + idusuario + " ]";
}
```

}

**servicio usuario**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.sefarcol.logica.impl;

import com.mycompany.sefarcol.datos.servicio.ConsultaServicioLocal;
import com.mycompany.sefarcol.logica.ServicioUsuarioLocal;
import com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Usuario;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Gil
 */
@Stateless
public class ServicioUsuario implements ServicioUsuarioLocal {

@EJB
private ConsultaServicioLocal consultaServicioLocal;

@Override
public Usuario obtenerUsuarioPorNombreYPassword(String nombre, String password) {
    String namedQuery = "Usuario.findByNombrePassword";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("nombre", nombre);
    parametros.put("password", password);
    return consultaServicioLocal.buscarPorConsultaNombradaSimple(namedQuery, parametros);
}

@Override
public List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuarios() {
    String namedQuery = "Usuario.findAll";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    return consultaServicioLocal.buscarPorConsultaNombrada(namedQuery, parametros);
}

@Override
public List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuariosPorNombre(String nombre) {
    String namedQuery = "Usuario.findByNombre";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("nombre", nombre);
    return consultaServicioLocal.buscarPorConsultaNombrada(namedQuery, parametros);
}

@Override
public List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuariosPorPassword(String password) {
    String namedQuery = "Usuario.findByPassword";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("password", password);
    return consultaServicioLocal.buscarPorConsultaNombrada(namedQuery, parametros);
}


@Override
public Usuario obtenerUsuarioNombre(String nombre) {
    String namedQuery = "Usuario.findByNombre";
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("nombre", nombre);        
    return consultaServicioLocal.buscarPorConsultaNombradaSimple(namedQuery, parametros);
}
```

}

**index bean**

```
import com.mycompany.sefarcol.logica.ServicioUsuarioLocal;
import com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Empleado;
import com.mycompany.sefarcoldatos.Usuario;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexander Gil
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {

@EJB
private ServicioUsuarioLocal servicioUsuarioLocal;
private Usuario usuario;
private List<Usuario> listaDeUsuarios;
private boolean loggedIn;
private String usuarioLogueo;
private String passwordLogueo;
private Empleado empleadoLogueado;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of IndexBean
 */
public IndexBean() {

}

@PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {
    usuario = new Usuario();
    listaDeUsuarios = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
}

public void listenerBotonInicioDeSesion() {
    List<Usuario> usuariosEncontrados = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerTodosLosUsuarios();
    for (Usuario u : usuariosEncontrados) {
        System.out.println("" + u.getIdusuario());
    }

}

public void prueba() {
    Usuario nombreUsuario = servicioUsuarioLocal.obtenerUsuarioNombre(usuarioLogueo);
    System.out.println("usuario encontrado " + nombreUsuario.getNombre());
}

public void listenerValidarInicioDeSesion() {

}

public List<Usuario> getListaDeUsuarios() {
    return listaDeUsuarios;
}

public void setListaDeUsuarios(List<Usuario> listaDeUsuarios) {
    this.listaDeUsuarios = listaDeUsuarios;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}

public Empleado getEmpleadoLogueado() {
    return empleadoLogueado;
}

public void setEmpleadoLogueado(Empleado empleadoLogueado) {
    this.empleadoLogueado = empleadoLogueado;
}
```

}

**index xhtml**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <p:outputPanel style="width: 100%; float: left">
                <h3>BIENVENIDO A ERP SEFARCOL</h3>               
            </p:outputPanel>
            <h:form class="form" style="text-align: center; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%;">                   
                <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obligatorio" 
                             value="#{indexBean.usuario.nombre}"                                 
                             pt:placeholder="Usuario"/>                               

                <h:inputSecret required="true" value="#{indexBean.usuario.password}"
                               requiredMessage="Campo Obligatorio"                                  
                               pt:placeholder="Password"/>
                <h:commandButton
                        value="Iniciar Sesion"
                        actionListener="#{indexBean.listenerBotonInicioDeSesion()}"
                        action="principal.xhtml"/>

            </h:form>
        </div>
        <ul class="bg-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</h:body>
```